# addObject to MutableSet crashes - reason: 'Unacceptable type of value for to-many relationship

Tags: iphone, objective-c, core-data

im trying to add a "to many" relationship object into a existing entry.
my code looks like this:

```
    User *user = [self fetchUserwithInformation:firstName lastName:lastName];
    NSMutableSet *userRecord;
    userRecord = [person mutableSetValueForKey: @"userInformation"];

    Information *information = (Information *)[NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"Information" inManagedObjectContext:managedObjectContext];

    information.age = @"99";
    information.gender = @"m";

    NSSet *set = [NSSet setWithObject:information];
    [userRecord addObject:information];
```

this code crashes due to an uncaught exception:

```
'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'Unacceptable type of value for to-many relationship: property = "userInformation"; desired type = NSSet; given type = __NSArrayM; value = ( ...some values...
```

i think i am adding a NSSet (setWithObject:information)...?

thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

You're adding the array `information` to `userRecord` rather than the set that you created with that array.

The error message is telling you exactly what the problem is - you're passing an array into something that is expecting a set.

I'm surprised that Xcode didn't warn you that the `set` variable is unused.